# Javascript load image in canvas without losing quality

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I use a canvas element to visualize an image because I need to manipulate image pixel.
When I load the image in an `img` tag it has a good quality, but when I load the image using `canvas` it is pixelated.
This is the result:
[with img tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YImhH.jpg)

[with canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv8gi.png)

How i can resolve this?

**---- EDIT -----**  I have partially solve, but the result it is not yet the best.
the new image and the code:
[with img tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YImhH.jpg)

[with canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQM11.png)

Code:

```
    var c = document.getElementById("c"); //canvas
    var i = document.getElementById("i"); //element from which take the dimensions 
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "./rendering-sito/renderoutput/v6p-x-render/jpg60/v6p-x-render_Camera0010010.jpg";


    c.width  = i.width;
    c.height  = i.height;
    c.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
```

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Show us some code, possibly the resolution of the canvas is wrong.